# stack function python error

Tags: python, stack

I created the following `stack` class for a project and am having trouble getting it to function properly. I can't tell if i made the error or it is an error in the main function i was given by my TA, anyways here is my code:

```
class Stack:
    #takes in the object as input argument
    #will not return anything 
    def __init__(self):
         #initialise an instance variable to an empty list.
         self.items=[]

    #takes in the object as input argument
    #return value Type: True or False
    def isEmpty(self):
         #check if the list is empty or not. If empty, return True else return False
         if self.items == []:
             return True
         else:
             return False


    #takes in the object as the first argument
    #takes the element to be inserted into the list as the second argument
    #should not return anything
    def push(self, x):
        #add the element to be inserted at the end of the list
        self.items.append(x)
    #takes in the object as the input argument
    #if the list is not empty then returns the last element deleted from the list. If the list is empty, don't return anything 
    def pop(self):
         #check if the list is Empty
         #if Empty: print the list is empty
         #if the list is not empty, then remove the last element from the list and return it 
         if self.isEmpty()==True:
             print("the list is empty")
         else:
           return self.items.pop()
     #takes in the object as the input argument
     #should not return anything
     def printContents(self):
          #if the list is not empty, then print each element of the list
          print("The content of the list is", self.items)
```

Based on the comments can anyone give me any advice on how I might make this work more appropriately? Sorry I am not a computer scientist and i am trying my hardest to understand classes and functions for my python class.

```
from stack import *

def main():
    s = Stack()
    s.push(1)
    s.pop()
    s.pop()
    s.push(2)
    s.push(3)
    s.push(4)
    s.printContents()

 main()
```

Comment: "having trouble getting it to function properly" -- Can you be more specific?  The only problem that I see is that `printContents` only prints the "top" of the stack instead of the full stack as the comment implies.

Comment: Show how you are using the class. What makes you think it is not working properly?

Comment: ok well my first problem is for the pop function i am supposed to check if the list is empty or not, im not sure how to check back to the isEmpty function

Comment: if you look at my pop function i just edited it keeps telling me isEmpty is not defined

Comment: Nothing is wrong with this code it works fine, show me what you are trying

Comment: from stack import *
 
def main():
    s = Stack()
    s.push(1)
    s.pop()
    s.pop()
    s.push(2)
    s.push(3)
    s.push(4)
    s.printContents()
 
main()

Comment: use `self.isEmpty()`

Comment: @NoahDukehart update it on your question

Comment: i added the main function, i continually get the error "IndexError: pop from empty list"

Comment: Its `self.isEmpty()` not `self.isEmpty`

Comment: are you importing this script to a different file? why are you importing from stack. you pushed only one element into list and popped it out. then you are trying to pop an element from an empty list which is not accepted as empty list doesn't have index defined

Comment: my expected outputs are "The list is empty
The contents of the list is: 2 3 4"

Comment: i can now get it to print "The list is empty" but cannot get it to continue on

Answer (score 0):

Modify your pop definition in class to this

```
def pop(self):

    #check if items is empty
    if len(self.items)==0:
        #if empty
        return "Nothing to pop"

    else:
        #if not empty
        return str(self.items.pop())+" Popped"
```

Comment: If he changes `pop` to what you suggest, how will he then write his main function?

Comment: @PaulRooney i didn't get you exactly, that pop is still inside class

Comment: This is awkward as it returns 1 thing or 2 things depending on whether it succeeded ...

Comment: You are advocating returning a string if its empty, or a tuple if its not. If he actually wants to read the popped item in `main` and or know if the stack was empty how would he do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a good look in spaces and alignment. For example `printContents` is not properly aligned. Note the proper alignment is very, very important in python.

Also you are not printing in `printContents`. This should work:

```
class Stack:
    #takes in the object as input argument
    #will not return anything 
    def __init__(self):
         #initialise an instance variable to an empty list.
         self.items=[]

    #takes in the object as input argument
    #return value Type: True or False
    def isEmpty(self):
         #check if the list is empty or not. If empty, return True else return False
         if self.items == []:
             return True
         else:
             return False


    #takes in the object as the first argument
    #takes the element to be inserted into the list as the second argument
    #should not return anything
    def push(self, x):
        #add the element to be inserted at the end of the list
        self.items.append(x)
    #takes in the object as the input argument
    #if the list is not empty then returns the last element deleted from the list. If the list is empty, don't return anything 
    def pop(self):
         #check if the list is Empty
         #if Empty: print the list is empty
         #if the list is not empty, then remove the last element from the list and return it 
         if self.isEmpty():
           print("the list is empty")
         else:
           return self.items.pop()

    #takes in the object as the input argument
    #should not return anything
    def printContents(self):
          #if the list is not empty, then print each element of the list
          print("the contents of the list are", self.items)

def main():
    s = Stack()
    s.push(1)
    s.pop()
    s.pop()
    s.push(2)
    s.push(3)
    s.push(4)
    s.printContents()

main()
```

You can see it working online here:

https://repl.it/BZW4

Answer (score 0):

Everybody has to start sometime so no worries, and I hope you are not offended by my extended critique, as I am just trying to be helpful.

You probably want the top declaration to be:

```
class Stack(object):
```

Leaving off the (object): part is a deprecated form that makes certain features of the class different in ways you probably don't want.

Secondly, declaring an isEmpty method is not really a normal "pythonic" approach. The strong expected python convention is to simply check the truth value of your object, with empty being False. Typical python users of your class will not expect an isEmpty method. You can control the behavior of your object's truth value by defining the special **nonzero** which you could write like this:

```
def __nonzero__(self):
    return bool(self.items)
```

This way somebody could use your class like:

```
stack = Stack()
stack.append("apple")
stack.append("pear")
if stack:
   print "stack has stuff in it"
else:
   print "stack is empty"
```

Moreover, there are other things you should overload to make a good stack class. For example you ought support len(stack) and you ought to be able to iterate over your stack. You can define special **len** and **iter** methods to do this. Notice if you define the **len** then you don't need to define the **iszero** (python will consider your stack False if **len** returns 0 and you have not defined **iszero**).

Your printContents method will not print or write anything without a print or write statement, but will return the last element in the stack and throw an index error if the stack is empty. To iterate over each item and print it you could write it like this (from the top item of stack to the first one):

```
def printContents(self):
    for item in reversed(self.items):
       print item
```

However it would be more pythonic to define an iteration method and the use that, so your user can iterate over your stack and print it themselves:

```
def __iter__(self):
   for item in self.items:
       yield item

# later in code .....

stack = Stack()
stack.append("apple")
stack.append("pear")
for item in stack:
   print item
```

Hopefully these tips may prove useful. Keep at it, and you will get it before long.